How can I expose an argument tuple type in a trait?
I am trying to use ffi_helpers::split_closure, which Michael F. Bryan describes in his blog post.
split_closure takes a FnMut, but I need to do this even for closures that are FnOnce. This can be done by wrapping it with an Option:
pub fn fn_mut_from_fn_once<A, R>(fn_once: impl FnOnce(A) -> R) -> impl FnMut(A) -> R {
    let mut fn_once = Some(fn_once);
    move |arg| {
        let fn_once = fn_once.take().unwrap();
        fn_once(arg)
    }
}

This only works with a unary FnOnce, however. So I tried to write this in terms of a helper trait:

pub trait AsFnMut<Args, Ret> {
    fn as_fn_mut(self) -> impl FnMut(/* TODO how to pass arg types? */) -> Ret;
}

// per-arity impls (TODO move to a macro):

impl<Func, Ret> AsFnMut<(), Ret> for Func
where
    Func: FnOnce() -> Ret,
{
    fn as_fn_mut(self) -> impl FnMut() -> Ret {
        let mut fn_once = Some(self);
        #[allow(non_snake_case)]
        move |/*args*/| {
            let fn_once = fn_once.take().unwrap();
            fn_once()
        }
    }
}

impl<Func, Ret, A> AsFnMut<(A,), Ret> for Func
where
    Func: FnOnce(A) -> Ret,
{
    fn as_fn_mut(self) -> impl FnMut(A) -> Ret {
        let mut fn_once = Some(self);
        #[allow(non_snake_case)]
        move |A| {
            let fn_once = fn_once.take().unwrap();
            fn_once(A)
        }
    }
}

impl<Func, Ret, A, B> AsFnMut<(A, B), Ret> for Func
where
    Func: FnOnce(A, B) -> Ret,
{
    fn as_fn_mut(self) -> impl FnMut(A, B) -> Ret {
        let mut fn_once = Some(self);
        #[allow(non_snake_case)]
        move |A, B| {
            let fn_once = fn_once.take().unwrap();
            fn_once(A, B)
        }
    }
}

I'm having a lot of trouble with that first TODO though.
How can I allow the impls to define the trait bounds on the trait's method?
I'd like to do something like this:
pub trait AsFnMut<Args, Ret> {
    type SpecificFnMutTrait;
    fn as_fn_mut(self) -> impl SpecificFnMutTrait;
}

But that is obviously wrong because I want a trait bound for SpecificFnMutTrait, not a type.

On nightly this can be done with an associated type:
#![feature(impl_trait_in_assoc_type)]

pub trait AsFnMut<Args, Ret> {
    type Output;
    fn as_fn_mut(self) -> Self::Output;
}

// per-arity impls (TODO move to a macro):

impl<Func, Ret> AsFnMut<(), Ret> for Func
where
    Func: FnOnce() -> Ret,
{
    type Output = impl FnMut() -> Ret;
    fn as_fn_mut(self) -> Self::Output {
        let mut fn_once = Some(self);
        #[allow(non_snake_case)]
        move || {
            let fn_once = fn_once.take().unwrap();
            fn_once()
        }
    }
}

impl<Func, Ret, A> AsFnMut<(A,), Ret> for Func
where
    Func: FnOnce(A) -> Ret,
{
    type Output = impl FnMut(A) -> Ret;
    fn as_fn_mut(self) -> Self::Output {
        let mut fn_once = Some(self);
        #[allow(non_snake_case)]
        move |A| {
            let fn_once = fn_once.take().unwrap();
            fn_once(A)
        }
    }
}

impl<Func, Ret, A, B> AsFnMut<(A, B), Ret> for Func
where
    Func: FnOnce(A, B) -> Ret,
{
    type Output = impl FnMut(A, B) -> Ret;
    fn as_fn_mut(self) -> Self::Output {
        let mut fn_once = Some(self);
        #[allow(non_snake_case)]
        move |A, B| {
            let fn_once = fn_once.take().unwrap();
            fn_once(A, B)
        }
    }
}

On stable I don't think this can be done.

Oh wow, never would have found that, thanks. I guess the closest thing in stable rust would be to just have AsFnMut0, AsFnMut1, AsFnMut2, etc?

@MHebes Then calling will need to use UFCS - very inconvenient. You can return Box<dyn FnMut()> but that will have a performance penalty.
